# Как написать RegEx для извлечения N-го значения из CSV-подобной строки используя regexp_substr()

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle, oracle12c, posix

Как можно расширить следующее регулярное выражение (в POSIX стандарте), таким образом чтобы в качестве разделителя строк могли выступать значения `,`, `;`, `/`,  , т.е. комбинации запятой, точки с запятой, слеша, пробелов и символа табуляции.

Пример исходных данных:

```
ID  EMAIL
--  --------------------------------------------------
1   NULL
2   mail1@domain.com
3   mail1@domain.com; mail2@domain.com, mail3@mail.com
4   mail1@domain.com, mail2@domain.com
5   mail1@domain.com mail2@domain.com
```

В  [данном `DB Fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5a288108cfbeb9a80505366ccf1ddc38) я попытался извлечь второй email из каждой строки и хотел бы получить следующий результат (**выходной датасет**):

```
ID  EMAIL
--  --------------------------------------------------
1   NULL
2   NULL
3   mail2@domain.com
4   mail2@domain.com
5   mail2@domain.com
```

Т.е. в результате не должны присутствовать символы разделители: `,`, `;`, `/`,  
Я попытался добавить POSIX значение `[:space:]` для того чтобы обрабатывать пробелы и знаки табуляции, но результат оказался неверным:

```
select
  id,
  regexp_substr (email, '(.*?)(([[:space:],;/])|($))', 1, 2, null, 1) as second_email
from tab;

ID  EMAIL
--  --------------------------------------------------
1   NULL
2   NULL
3   NULL
4   NULL
5   mail2@domain.com
```

Подскажите как исправить POSIX RegEx.

**NOTE:** я работаю с Oracle 12.2, который не понимает RegEx символы такие как `\s`, поэтому приходится использовать только регулярки, которые поддерживаются POSIX стандартом.

PS в данном примере я всегда извлекаю второе значение из строки - это упрощенный (минимальный воспроизводимый) пример. На самом деле это часть функции, которая должна уметь извлекать любое N-ое значение (`N` будет передаваться в функцию в качестве параметра).

Comment: Наверное, `regexp_substr (email, '[^[:space:],;/]+', 1, 2) as second_email`? `2` — это ваш `N`-й параметр.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, спасибо, в DB fiddle с упрощенным примером этот вариант работает. Сейчас протестирую этот RegEx в своей функции в более сложных случаях...

Comment: Это выражение находит все последовательности одного и более символов, отличных от пробельных символов, запятой, точки с запятой и символа косой черты. Такой шаблон будет работать во всех случаях, когда нужные данные всегда разделены этими символами. У вас в вопросе нет информации о `/`, однако в примере кода этот символ присутствует.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, нет к сожалению в более сложной функции этот вариант не сработал. Придется наверное писать новый вопрос и приводить тело большой функции...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, а можно как-то исправить только среднюю часть следующего RegEx: `'(.*?)((' || '[[:space:],;/]' || ')|($))'` ?

Comment: Вы хотите изменить только `[[:space:],;/]`? Но у вас в строках рядом с разделителями есть и пробельные символы, и `[[:space:],;/]` их и находит. Вам нужно что-то делать с `.*?`.

Comment: Что-то вроде `'([^[:space:]].*?)((' || '[[:space:],;/]' || ')|($))'`

Comment: _который не понимает RegEx символы такие как \s_, а с каких пор он их не понимает?

Comment: @0xdb Внутри квадратных скобок.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew А, я понял вообще, теперь вижу.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, спасибо, по-моему это оно! Можете оформить как ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регулярное выражение `(.*?)(([[:space:],;/])|($))` не всегда находит нужное совпадение, потому что `(.*?)` также находит пустую строку, а у вас в строках рядом с разделителями есть и пробельные символы, и `[[:space:],;/]` их и находит. Другими словами, вместо нужного значения `(.*?)` захватывает пустую строку, `[[:space:],;/]` находит пробел после, например, запятой, и возвращается совпадение.

Поэтому, вместо `(.*?)` нужно подставить такой шаблон, чтобы он не находил пустую строку, например

```sql
'([^[:space:]].*?)((' || '[[:space:],;/]' || ')|($))'
```

(Я использую оригинальный синтаксис со всеми подмасками, хотя я не уверен, нужны они здесь или нет.)

Шаблон `([^[:space:]].*?)` не найдёт пустой строки, так как `[^[:space:]]` требует одного любого символа кроме пробельного, и именно с этого символа и начнётся совпадение.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение того, почему не работал RegEx из вопроса!

Answer (score 4):

Выглядит, что [следующие регулярки работают](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9301054dbf9c5d3a29bcccd336da48c5):

```
select id, regexp_substr (
    email, '(\w.*?)(([[:space:],;/])|($))', 1, 2, null, 1) as second_email
from tab
/
select id, regexp_substr (
    email, '(.*?)(([[:space:],;/]+)|($))', 1, 2, null, 1) as second_email
from tab
```

Обе выводят:

```
        ID SECOND_EMAIL                                      
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1                                                   
         2                                                   
         3 mail2@domain.com                                  
         4 mail2@domain.com
```

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT tab.id, jsontable.email_num, jsontable.email
FROM tab
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE('["' || REGEXP_REPLACE(tab.email, '[,;\/ ]+', '","') || '"]',
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (email_num FOR ORDINALITY,
                                      email VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) jsontable;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=182ab5331fc09c25ab534002c56c634f